# Disable deselect on smart-table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, smart-table

I have a smart-table like this:

```
<table id="mytable" st-safe-src="ABCSet" st-table="displayed" class="table table-responsive portlet-body panel-body">
                    <thead>
                        <tr >
                            <th >1</th>
                            <th >2</th>
                            <th >3</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>                        
                    <tbody data-ng-dblclick="scrollTo()">    
                        <tr data-ng-repeat="row in displayed" st-select-row="row" st-select-mode="single">
                            <td data-ng-click="$parent.selR(row);">{{row.randomP.randomD}}</td>
                            <td data-ng-click="$parent.selR(row);">{{row.randomP.randomD}}</td>
                            <td data-ng-click="$parent.selR(row);">{{row.randomP.randomD}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

It works fine, but I display the data on some labels under the table, so I want to disable deselect when the user click on the current selected row (as you can see I use doubleClick for a scroll event, so It's pretty weird when the selected row is deselect when want to call it).

Comment: Need the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ng-watch for this.

```
    // get selected row
    $scope.selectedId = 0;
    // fired when table rows are selected
    $scope.$watch('displayedCollection', function (row) {
        row.filter(function (r) {
            if (r.isSelected && r.id != $scope.selectedId) {
                $scope.selectedId = r.id;
                getInfo(r.id);
            }
            else{
                $scope.selectedId = r.id;
            }
        })
    }, true);
```